# Custom tooltip for multi series xy

Tags: tooltip, scatter-plot, c3.js

I am using this code to customize a tooltip on a multiline xy scatter chart. How would I modify the tooltip so each series would have its own unique label, nameArr, nameArr1, nameArr2...? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laguna92651/t1aLbc0d/)

```
  tooltip: {
    format: {
        title: function(x) {
            var indOfVal = engagmentArr.indexOf(x);
            return nameArr[indOfVal - 1]
        },
       name:function(){
        return engagmentArr[0]; 
        }
    },
},
```

Comment: could you please setup jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle url [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laguna92651/t1aLbc0d/)

Answer (score 0):

General solution is to store tooltips separately from dot chart itself.

And access them by **group id** and **data index**:

```
var tooltips = {
    mention1: ['ROA=5.1%','ROA=8.1%','ROA=4.1%','ROA=10.1%'],
    mention2: ['ROA=5.1%','ROA=8.1%','ROA=4.1%','ROA=10.1%'],
    mention3: ['2000 ROA=2.2%','2001 ROA=8.2%','2002 ROA=5.2%','2005 ROA=12.2%'],
    mention4: ['2000 ROA=2.2%','2001 ROA=8.2%','2002 ROA=5.2%','2005 ROA=12.2%']
}

var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        xs: {
            mention1: 'engagement1',
            mention2: 'engagement2',
            mention3: 'engagement3',
            mention4: 'engagement4'
        },

        columns: [
            ['engagement1', 140, 150, 157, 220],
            ['mention1', 2237, 4456, 3300, 1453],
            ['engagement2', 40, 50, 57, 120],
            ['mention2', 2237, 4456, 3300, 1453],
            ['engagement3', 150, 155, 165, 230],
            ['mention3', 2037, 4756, 3100, 1053],
            ['engagement4', 50, 55, 65, 130],
            ['mention4', 2037, 4756, 3100, 1053]
        ],
        type: 'scatter'
    },
    point: {
        r: function(d) {
            return d.value * 0.005;
        },
    },
    tooltip: {
        contents: function (d) {
          var id = d[0].id;                   // 'mention1', 'mention2' ...
          var index = d[0].index;             // 1,2,3,4 ...

          // replace plain data with custom markup or copy c3's default
          return tooltips[id][index];         // 'ROA=...'
       }
    }
});
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/t1aLbc0d/9/)

Comment: Worked great, thanks. The first set of data works fine when I replace the mention: hard coded data with  variables **Data1**, **Data2** and **Data3**, but when I replace the mention2: hard coded data with **Data4**, **Data5** and **Data6**, the code breaks, any thoughts? The **Data1** variables are generated in a Filemaker database. I updated my jsfiddle to show **Datan** placement. If I only replace the mention2 and leave mention hard coded, it still breaks.

Comment: Can you give a link to updated fiddle? Previous link seems to contain old code.

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/laguna92651/t1aLbc0d/) The external data sources that do not work are commented out, thanks. @Dmitry

Comment: I don't understand what kind of data was added. Shouldn't it be one level upper at object? 
Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/t1aLbc0d/8/

Comment: The **Data2** is a reference to a field in my Filemaker db. It would be the data set ['engagement', 40, 50, 57, 120], **Data2** is the syntax needed to access the data. The code is being run in a web viewer in Filemaker. The code works witth  **Data2**,  **Data1**  and **Data3** replacing the hard code data set. When I add  **Data5**  **Data4**  **Data6**  to the second series the code breaks.

Comment: See updated solution. I removed specific data structure to make idea more clear.

Comment: This is the solution you are referring to correct? [This Solution?](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/t1aLbc0d/9/). This works in the browser but doesn't work in my database web viewer, the two series solution you had originally posted did work in my database web viewer, it just didn't work when I used arrays pulled in externally. I am going to go through both pieces of code to see if I can get the 4 series solution working, thanks. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Code is working fine, made mistake in copy code over. How would I add the x and y values to the tooltip on seperate lines, thank you?

Comment: You can return any custom html markup from tooltip.contents function. A simplest example is to put a line break tag instead of space: https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/t1aLbc0d/10/

Comment: Thanks, I was able to add what I needed. I would also like to change the font type (Arial) and font size, but can't find anything that gives the syntax to make those changes. Would those changes just be added to the return expression?